# Running winrs command from Team Build Hangs

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a step in my TFS build workflow which attempts to invoke a command on a remote machine using winrs.  I use an invoke process task and give it powershell as the command then pass in a script which contains something like

```
winrs -r:remote.server.com ipconfig
```

The command runs just fine and I can see the output in the build logs, however the whole thing seems to stall at that point.  I can log into the remote box and confirm that no ipconfig is running so that process has finished but it is like winrs isn't returning.  Is there some trick I'm missing perhaps a

```
-justBloodyWork
```

flag?

Comment: I have the same problem with job for pipeline implemented in Go Release Management.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/135070/why-does-my-powershell-script-hang-when-called-in-psexec-via-a-batch-cmd-file

This is a common issue with POSH. The problem is that stdin hangs. Try this: winrs -r:remote.server.com ipconfig < NUL

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo build server runs into the same issue. < NUL works for bat files, but < is broke in powershell.  To supply standard input in powershell, pipe in $null:

`$null | winrs -r:remote.server.com ipconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Try -nop option. A user's profile always gets loaded on the remote system and this may be causing issues.

Comment: I gave that a shot and the process still hangs in exactly the same way.